# Ubuntu 12.04 installer and gparted do not detect the existing windows partitions

Tags: 12.04, installation, gparted, gpt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix MBR partition prior to Ubuntu Installation? A partition overlaps GPT backup sectors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150378/how-to-fix-mbr-partition-prior-to-ubuntu-installation-a-partition-overlaps-gpt)

I just bought a new laptop that comes with Windows 7 preinstalled and I want to install Ubuntu alongside with it.

The system came with 5 partitions:

- System partition
- Unknown partition
- NTFS partition (the one with windows)
- NTFS partition (to be used for data)
- A recovery partition

I had removed the NTFS data partition and shrinked the windows partition to make room for Ubuntu as it will be my main OS.

The problem is that when I boot with the live CD, the installation program does not detect any of the partitions and tries to use the whole disk (/dev/sda) to install Ubuntu.

When I start the Live CD, I can see that gparted does not detect them:
[image]

But the disk utility can:
[image]

Also, while looking through askubuntu I've found similar questions asked before that did not solve my issue, but I have run the commands suggested with the following output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -lu

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60563 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2902cc6d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fixparts /dev/sda
FixParts 0.8.4

Loading MBR data from /dev/sda

This disk appears to be a GPT disk. Use GNU Parted or GPT fdisk on it!
Exiting!

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Error: Unable to satisfy all constraints on the partition.                

Error: /dev/sr0: unrecognised disk label
```

Does anyone know how can I workaround this?

EDIT:
I have added a couple of screenshots so people can see better what the problem is.

Also I have run gdisk as requested by John, here is the output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo gdisk -l
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.5

Problem opening -l for reading! Error is 2.
The specified file does not exist!

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo gdisk /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.5

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
33 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 976773168 sectors, 465.8 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 91B5A850-8718-4D8C-AA48-4DA569E5BEAE
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 976773134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 716402654 sectors (341.6 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          411647   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI system partition
   2          411648          673791   128.0 MiB   0C01  Microsoft reserved part
   3          673792       209174527   99.4 GiB    0700  Basic data partition
   4       925575168       976773167   24.4 GiB    2700  Basic data partition

Command (? for help): v

Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
33 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.

Identified 1 problems!
```

Comment: Would you mind trying `sudo gdisk -l` and putting the output in your question? gdisk is in the gdisk package along with fixparts, so you probably already have it installed.

Comment: @JohnSGruber Thanks for you answer. I think we are in the right direction. I've installed gdisk, run it, and you can see the output in the question. There is an error detected, but I am not sure how to fix it. Which other tool should I use for that?

Comment: I think that the solution to this is in this other [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150378/how-to-fix-mbr-partition-prior-ubuntu-installation), I will test and let you know.

Comment: If the other question is an exact dusplicate, shouldn't we mark it as duplicate?